# XDG Base Directory environment variables not respected by notionally compliant software

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, environment-variables, xdg

### The goal

I'm running Arch Linux. I want to store all config/data/cache/state files in subdirectories of `~/local`, like so:

```
~
├── downloads
├── documents
└── local
    ├── data
    ├── state
    ├── config
    └── cache
```

### The attempt

In order to do this, I've set environment variables as follows:

```sh
# set up XDG directories
export XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/local/data
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/local/config
export XDG_STATE_HOME=$HOME/local/state
export XDG_CACHE_HOME=$HOME/local/cache

# enable compliance
export ZDOTDIR=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh
export HISTFILE=$XDG_STATE_HOME/zsh/history
```

This is currently placed in `/etc/zsh/zshenv` (as I use `zsh`), however, I've also tried placing this in `~/local/config/zsh/.zshenv` and only setting `$ZDOTDIR` globally.

I can see the environment variables set in the shell:

```sh
% echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME                                        
# /home/myuser/local/config

% echo $ZDOTDIR                                                
# /home/myuser/local/config/zsh
```

---

### The problem

Many, but not all, programs that I run just don't seem to respect the variables I've set.

For instance, [`Hyprland`](https://hyprland.org) ignores `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and creates a default configuration file at `~/.config/hypr/hyprland.conf`, despite `~/local/config/hypr/hyprland.conf` existing. It then reads the file *it* created and complains about my configuration not having been modified. The same applies to my terminal emulator, [`kitty`](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty), which *explicitly implements XDG Base Directory*.

Other programs however, like [`tealdeer`](https://github.com/dbrgn/tealdeer) and `zsh` itself, respect the variables and put files in the directories I specified.

Why is software that supposedly supports the standard not changing behaviour based on the environment variables I set?

Comment: What is the question here? Please ask a proper question ending with a `?` character.

Comment: @Destroy666 Why is software that supposedly supports the standard not changing behaviour based on the environment variables I set?

Comment: How did you verify that the variables _were_ placed in the software's environment?

Comment: "Why does X software decide to not do something?" is opinion-based, which is not allowed here and might result in a closed question.

Comment: @u1686_grawity This ended up being the problem. Thanks for pointing me to it, and not just dismissing my question about software behaviour on a forum about software behaviour :p

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem *with all the helpful advice from the comments.* Huzzah.

The issue was that because I defined the environment variables in `/etc/zsh/zshenv`, they would only be set in Zsh shells, and *not* during a graphical login, done through a display manager. Testing this theory by logging into a different TTY and starting Hyprland manually from the command line proved successful.

To solve it, I followed the advice [in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables#Using_pam_env) and defined variables in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`:

```sh
# ...

XDG_CONFIG_HOME     DEFAULT=@{HOME}/local/config
XDG_STATE_HOME      DEFAULT=@{HOME}/local/state
XDG_DATA_HOME       DEFAULT=@{HOME}/local/data
XDG_CACHE_HOME      DEFAULT=@{HOME}/local/cache
ZDOTDIR             DEFAULT=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/zsh
```

Hence, these variables will now be loaded no matter the context and Hyprland (and by extension some programs run directly from it) will respect the preferences I set.